# Find and replace using * equivalent in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string

I want to replace the string "Private room in house" with "Private" in a column in a dataframe

I have tried

```
df['room'] = df['room'].str.replace("Private[]","Private")
```

putting all the various regular expression characters in the [] but nothing works. All I have succeeded in doing is removing the space after Private.

I have looked at re.sub but haven't managed to get anything to work for me. I'm pretty new to Python so this is probably a simple problem but I can't find the answer anywhere

Comment: The regular expression should be `Private.*`

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df['room'] = df['room'].str.replace('Private.*','Private', regex=True)
```

Or with a look behind:

```
df['room'] = df['room'].str.replace('(?<=Private).*', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't believe it was that simple. ".*" was about the only option I didn't try

Comment: @Agatha there is a difference between [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (used in shells for instance) `abc*` and [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `abc.*` ;)

Comment: Thanks again Mozway, I used to be a Unix admin so globbing would be my default thinking